# Using different keys for map & reduce

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a current Couch DB that stores *activities* that happen on different *nodes*. I'm currently getting a count of how many *activities* have happened on each node using the following:

**Map:**

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.node._id, 1);
}
```

**Reduce:**

```
_sum
```

This works great! Now, I'd like to allow it to be filterable by the timestamp. My first thought was to change the map to this:

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.node._id, doc.created], 1);
}
```

However that, of course, added the `created` flag to the key, so the reduce doesn't really work how I wanted anymore.

Is there a way that I can map by `node._id` and `created`, but reduce by only `node._id`?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, I looked into using `group_level`, however that only works with one key, and I need to be able to pass multiple keys to this index.

Comment: Upon further searching, it looks like this isn't possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571459/couchdb-view-query-with-multiple-key-values

Comment: Can you please provide an example value of the timestamp you want to sort with?

Comment: It's a unix timestamp (an integer representing the number of seconds since 1970).

Comment: Thats great. If I understand you right you want to be able to ask for "how many activities have happened on a particular  node"?

Comment: It's more "How many activities have happened on _these_ nodes (multiple `_id`s) between these timestamps?"